# Create new class with an instance of the inherited class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I would like to know how I could take an object from a function and place it and all it's attributes into another object.

```
class Something:
    def create(self):
        print('Creating')

class Foo(Something):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_something(self):
        print('Do somthing')


def bar():
    # Can not change this function
    return Something()

s = bar()

s.create() # 'Creating'

-- I want to do this --
f = Foo(s)

f.create()
f.do_something()
```

Limitations:

I cant alter `bar()`. I need to be able to access all of `Something`'s methods and attributes from `Foo`.  I would like to stay away form composition so that I can call `Foo.create()` directly (not like `Foo.something.create()`).

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` to `__init__(self, _, *args, **kwargs):`

```
>>> Foo(Something()).create()
Creating
>>> Foo(Something()).do_something()
Do somthing
```

I honestly don't see the problem here. Or why you want to supply an instance of `Something` when creating an instance of `Foo`, but there you go.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work if `Something` does not have a required constructor variable. Any idea how to get it to work with a constructor variable? Ex. Something.__init__(name): self.name = name

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll then you pass down those args when calling `__init__`. I have the feeling that you have some fundamental misconception about inheritance or method calling at some point here. Or you are trying to do something different from what your question suggests.

Comment: Dude, why the hostility? If you have a required constructor argument, it does not get passed down in `*args` from the `Something()` class thats already instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this solution, which Im not very happy with as it requires me to call the function twice.

```
class Something:
    def create(self):
        print('Creating')

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.sometthing = something

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)

    @some_special_decorator
    def create(self):
        return self.something.create()

    def do_something(self):
        print('Do somthing')


def bar():
    # Can not change this function
    return Something()

s = bar()

s.create() # 'Creating'

f = Foo(s)

f.create()
f.do_something()
```

Comment: Call what function twice?

Comment: Might not be twice, but I have to call `create()` in the Foo class. For instance, I cant use `super.create()`.